# Are Local Temp Tables in SQL Server Thread Safe?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've seen mixed answers on this even here on stack and hoping to find a definitive answer.  Are multiple parallel calls to the same stored procedure that internally creates local temp tables using inbound parameters going to collide with one another?  Basically are local temporary tables or any flavor of temporary tables thread safe.

Thank you!

Tim

Comment: Temp are only available to the connection that created them. If you are calling the same stored procedure at the same time on different connections you have absolutely no issue. This is why there is a distinction between temp tables and global temp tables. Global temp tables are visible to any connection.

Comment: Thx Sean but again i see many other articles that contradict this. Seems like a 50/50 thing on opinions of how this really works.  See my other comment below.

Comment: This isn't opinion. It is how temp tables work. I would like to see an article that contradicts that.

Comment: You guys act like asking the question about temp tables and thread safety is an alien question... i guess MSDN didn't think so...

Comment: Again guys... if i clear my browser history and cookies and go shop on amazon they are indeed using a service level account to run non-sensitive queries on the database... furthermore they are using connection pooling to know that when the number of web sessions managed by the web server trip a threshold they will open more connections to the database to distribute the load... WebMethods, WebSphere, ATG Dynamo... Even Apache does this...

Comment: 1st paragraph of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool completely shows you that using multiple sessions/threads within one database connection is why Connection pooling was invented...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temporary tables are related to sessions and you can not create same temporary table inside same session. For an example:

Create a temporary table in a session

```
CREATE TABLE #ThreadSafeTable
(
  Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
  SomeColumn VARCHAR(20)
)
```

Now when you try to create the same temp table in other session then SQL Server will give it a different name. Check the same in System Databases > Tempdb > Temporary tables

[image]

So, as long as each thread is running in a different session you won't be having an collation issues, which I always recommend. .
The case is different for global temporary table whose scope is "Sever".

**Edit-1**

To test that stored procedure having same temp table won't conflict with each other

Create below stored procedure

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyTestSP
AS
BEGIN TRY
    CREATE TABLE #ThreadSafeTable
(
  Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
  SomeColumn INT
)

INSERT INTO #ThreadSafeTable
VALUES (FLOOR(RAND()*(25-1)+1)),(CAST(FLOOR(RAND()*(25-1)+1) AS Varchar(20)))

SELECT *, Session_ID = @@SPID FROM #ThreadSafeTable

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'

DROP TABLE #ThreadSafeTable
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
    DECLARE @ErrorState INT;

    SELECT 
        @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
        @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
        @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();
        RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity,@ErrorState);
END CATCH
```

Above sp will create the same SP but fill random data to it. Now execute this SP multiple times in one window or different window

[image]

Comment: Anuj - Fantastic answer and thank you!  Could i trouble you for one more piece of clarity?  What about a procedure that internally creates a local temp table each time its called with differing data.  Meaning if within the same db session or across multiple db sessions are calling that procedure in parallel/synchronously what is the behavior/scope?

Comment: @TimWiley It won't. I have edited my answer with **Edit-1** where I have created a test which proves that stored procedure using TempTable won't conflict. Same result (of course with different SPID) will be appeared if you execute this sp from different window(session). Hope this will clear your doubt.

Answer (score 1):

What does thread safe have to do with it.  If it is a local temp then it is local to that stored procedure.  If you did not kill the local temp table it would still only be available to that connection.

Think about it.  If they were all using the same local temp then the call to create the local temp would fail if it was a common local temp.